# Calling javascript function to run php code

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to make a login page in which when you click logout it will log you out then refresh the page, however, whenever JavaScript $.get's it, it just doesn't run the php code, however it does refresh the page. Help would be much appreciated.

index.php

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function logOut() {
            $.get("logout.php");
            location.Reload();
            return false;
        }
   </script>
   <a href="#" onclick="logOut();">Log Out</a>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
    setcookie('username', '', 0);
    setcookie('password', '', 0);
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `href="logout.php"`, then redirect back to the last page?

Comment: You should unset sessions to logout and i can't find it at your code !
and also you should be sure of logout.php path , try with full url and till me what happened

Comment: Why do you store the password in a cookie?

Comment: For interface, and is it bad to use cookies, how should I do it?

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend storing their password in a cookie. This opens up many vulnerabilities. Is it atleast hashed?

Comment: Yes, md5 hashed. What is the safe alternative?

Comment: Simply not storing their password in a cookie at all - In what scenario would you need it? Using sessions is already a great improvement

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even recognize that. Thank you!

Comment: Use sessions to store logins for a limited time; eg an hour or so. Use cookies without passes (perhaps with a unique hash) to store logins for a longer period (remember-me functions).

Comment: Is there any code I can put on logout.php to make know if the page is actually running the code?

Comment: I didn't set any sessions because I'm fairly new at php. I tried using "http://localhost/logout.php" and the same reaction occurred.

Comment: Yes, just echo something: ```echo "loggedout";``` in your logout.php code.
In my example below you can then check what returndate has as a value.

Comment: Or you can check f12 (network tab) in chrome to see what the ajax call is doing.

Comment: you should provide us login code

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the refresh on success, or at least wait for the call to end.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function logOut() {
            $.get("logout.php" , returndata , function() {
            location.Reload(); });
        }
   </script>
   <a href="#" onclick="logOut();">Log Out</a>
```

Change your setcookie also to be removed immediately. The common method is entering a timestamp in the past:

```
setcookie('cookiename',0,( time() - 3600 ));
```

Comment: It's really weird, the page refreshes but the cookies still remain.

Comment: Are yous sure the page is logout.php? and not perhaps Logout.php or LogOut.php? And where is the file located? In the same directory as the requesting page? Perhaps you should use an absolute path? ```/logout.php```

Comment: Indeed it is.  It is in the same directory as index.php, all lowercase.

Comment: @user1340052 lol, then make a link to `logout.php`, like `<a href="/logout.php">Logout</a>`

Answer (score 3):

Why not use javascript to remove the cookies, rather than using php for the PHP cookies.

Answer (score 1):

According to [`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

```
setcookie('username', '', 0);
```

expires at the end of the session

> ***expire***
>       The time the cookie expires. This is a Unix timestamp so is in number of seconds since the epoch. In other words, you'll most likely set this with the time() function plus the number of seconds before you want it to expire. Or you might use mktime(). time()+60*60*24*30 will set the cookie to expire in 30 days. If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes).

If you want to remove the cookies, you should use some value other than `0`

```
setcookie('username', '', 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

**First of all** 
, you're implementing your logout function wrong.
If you want to remove all cookies (assuming your system isn't complex, say when you don't need to keep user preferencies like, theme, language, UI params)

Then `logout.php` should be similar to

```
<?php

//Will remove all cookies
if ( !empty($_COOKIE) ){
  foreach($_COOKIE as $key){
     //Set each key in past
     setcookie($key, null, time() - 84600);

  }
}

//Would destroy the session if it does exists
if ( !empty($_SESSION) ){
  session_destroy();
}

//Don't forget to redirect back to home page
header('Location: /');
exit();
```

if you're 100% sure the cookies are set, but `setcookie()` does not remove them, then probably 99% they are on a different path.

Make sure, when you set/remove them, they are on the same path.
`setcookie()` takes a 4th optional argument called `path`.

```
<?php

//So when you set a cookie
setcookie('cookie_key', 'cookie_value', time() + some_lifetime_in_seconds, '/');

//And when you remove a cookie:
setcookie('cookie_key', '', time() - 86400, '/');
```

**Second**
You shouldn't use AJAX-like logout function. It's unwise and a bit memory waste.

The code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function logOut() {
            $.get("logout.php");
            location.Reload();
            return false;
        }
   </script>
   <a href="#" onclick="logOut();">Log Out</a>
```

Should be rewritten as

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
 <a href="/logout.php">Log Out</a>
```